# Set checkbox value to true if Data in Datagridview exist else False

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I have a program and it looks like this

[image]

My Target here is how can I set the value of the checkbox to true if a certain Name exist and its value = True or else false

I have this code but its not working

```
    For Each dr As DataGridViewRow In Me.DataGridView1.Rows
                If dr.Cells(0).Value.ToString = "Button2" and dr.Cells(1).Value.ToString = "True" Then checkbox23.checked = True Else checkbox23.checked = False

and so on
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
            Next
        End Sub
```

any help is well appreciated TYSM

Comment: Is the grid bound to a data source?  If so, what is it?

Comment: By the way, the fact that you have a control named `checkbox23` does not bode well.  You should immediately change the name of every control to something meaningful.  Even if it doesn't help you, which I doubt would be the case, it may well help us, who you're asking for help from.

Comment: @jmcilhinney Sir ty for the respond my target here is to create an `if else` statement that finds a specific word and check if the data next to it is true or false then a checkbox will be enabled. Sorry for the improper posting the question

Answer (score 0):

Found my answer

```
  Public Function EnableByPermission(ByVal buttonName As String) As Boolean
        Dim Enable As Boolean = False

        ' Look over the Enumerable collection of Rows the one where the
        ' cell for ControlName contains the button name required
        Dim row = DataGridView1.Rows _
                  .Cast(Of DataGridViewRow)() _
                  .FirstOrDefault(Function(x) _
                      x.Cells("ControlName").Value.ToString = buttonName)


        ' If we found it then return the boolean value for the Access column      
        If row IsNot Nothing Then
            Enable = Convert.ToBoolean(row.Cells("Access").Value)
        End If
        Return Enable
    End Function
    Private Sub Form7_Shown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Shown
        CheckBox23.Checked = EnableByPermission("Button2")
    End Sub
```